# Resize function events fire 2 times more each time the window was resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On my site, I am trying to fix the navigation so that when the browser is getting resized from desktop to mobile size, the mobile menu works. I have the mobile menu working on initial load, and the desktop navigation working on initial load, but when I run the script in a `$(window).on('resize', function() {}` and click an item as depicted in my script, the event fires always `+1` each time the window was rested after a resize.

What I mean is, if I load the page, scale it into mobile size, click the menu and a dropdown item, the `click` event will fire once. Resize the window out and then back in, the `click` event will fire now 2 times, then 3, and so on, depending on how many times the browser was resized.

I'm not sure exactly what is going on in my resize script that is screwing everything up and I'm at my wits end at trying to figure it out. Normally people aren't sitting there resizing their browser from desktop to mobile, but my boss does when he show's clients a beta of their site and wants this to never be an issue.

Here is my resize script:

```
(function( $ ) {

    var id,
        $body = $('body'),
        $window = $( window ),
        $navSlider = $('.nav-slider'),
        $navMask = $( '.nav-mask' ),
        $navToggler = $( '.navbar-toggler' ),
        $parent = $( '.menu-item-has-children' ),
        $parentLink = $( '.dropdown-toggle' ),
        $childContainer = $( '.dropdown-menu' );

    $window.on( 'resize', function( e ) {

        clearTimeout(id);
        id = setTimeout(function() {

            close();

            var width = $window.width();

            if ( width < 992 ) {

                setHeightToNav();

                $navMask.on( 'click', function() { close() } );
                $navToggler.on( 'click', function() { open() } );

                $parentLink.on( 'click', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $this = $( this );   
                    $this.data( 'clicked', true );

                    console.log( $this.parent() );

                } )

            }

            if ( width >= 992 ) {
                resetNavHeight();
                console.clear();
            }
        }, 500 );

    } );


    function setHeightToNav() {
        if ( $body.hasClass( 'logged-in' ) ) {
            var $wpAdminBar = $( '#wpadminbar' ).outerHeight();
            $navSlider.css( { top: $wpAdminBar + 'px' } );
        }

        var $navHeight = $( '#header-container' ).outerHeight();
        $navSlider.css( { marginTop: $navHeight + 'px' } );

    }

    function resetNavHeight() {
        if ( $body.hasClass( 'logged-in' ) ) {
            $navSlider.css( { top: 0 + 'px' } );
        }
        $navSlider.css( { marginTop: 0 + 'px' } );
    }

    function close() {
        $body.removeClass( 'has-active-menu' );
        setTimeout( function() {
            $navSlider.removeClass( 'toggling' );
            $parent.removeClass( 'show' );
            $parentLink.attr( 'aria-expanded', false );
            $childContainer.removeClass( 'show' ).removeAttr( 'style' );
            $parentLink.data('clicked', false);
        }, 250 );
        console.log('close()');
    }

    function open() {
        $body.addClass( 'has-active-menu' );
        $navSlider.addClass( 'toggling' );
    }

})( jQuery );
```

I've tried my script both with AND without the `setTimeout` function and it happens exactly the same.

On the project, we are using Bootstrap 4, with the Bootstraps `Dropdown._clearMenus();` function commented out in the right places as it was causing conflicts with the functionality I wanted with the navigation.

A link to a site where you can see this is [here](http://freyproperty.wpengine.com/). It's a WordPress site as well if that matters for anything.

Any help is appreciated. I've been at this for several hours and am at my wits end.

Comment: Terrible practice to add new event listeners inside other event handlers when you don't understand the implications. Very rare that you ever need to do this

Comment: How would you suggest reworking this?

Comment: Move all those event listeners outside of resize and check window width inside them if needed

Answer (score 2):

`.on( 'click', function )` does not set the event listener, it *adds* an event listener. Try doing `off('click')` before setting it if you really need to set this listener here.

But note that any other 'click' listener for this element will also be removed.

That's for the quick fix. You could do better, but that would require more work (track with a boolean if you just changed "display mode", and add or remove the event listeners only then, for example).

Comment: When you say more work, you mean within the resize function or within the normal script firing it that the resize can relate to.